How to get a lightning-datatable's width correctly setup for horizontal scrolling?
When a related list is configured in a page, the table showing the related list values starts with this markup:
    <div lwc-392cvb27u8q="" class="slds-scrollable_y" style="width: 1245px;">
        <table lwc-392cvb27u8q="" class="slds-table slds-table_header-fixed ...

that appears so set the width to a value derived from the column table widths so that the columns shown are not squished up and the user can scroll to see the other columns.
I'd like to do this with in one of my LWCs that presents a lightning-datatable. Any suggestions on how to get a good width set? Using column-widths-mode="auto" the width of the containing panel appears to be used rather than the width of the table content. And that width is automatically adjusted when e.g. the browser window is resized.
(I don't see a clear explanation in this documentation of how to do this.)

Try by setting an initialWidth config param while configuring the columns.
html
<template>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
</template>

JS :
/**
 * Created by nagendrakumar.singh on 10/09/24.
 */

import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Label', fieldName: 'name' , initialWidth: 200},
    { label: 'Website', fieldName: 'website', type: 'url' , initialWidth: 200},
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone' , initialWidth: 200},
    { label: 'Balance', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency' , initialWidth: 200},
    { label: 'CloseAt', fieldName: 'closeAt', type: 'date' , initialWidth: 200},
    { label: 'CloseAt1', fieldName: 'closeAt1', type: 'date' , initialWidth: 200},
    { label: 'CloseAt2', fieldName: 'closeAt2', type: 'date' , initialWidth: 200},
];

export default class BaseDatatable extends LightningElement {

    data = [];
    columns = columns;

    connectedCallback() {
        const data = this.generateData({ amountOfRecords: 100 });
        this.data = data;
    }


    generateData({ amountOfRecords }) {
        return [...Array(amountOfRecords)].map((_, index) => {
            return {
                name: `Name (${index})`,
                website: 'www.salesforce.com',
                amount: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                phone: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000000000) + 1000000000}`,
                closeAt: new Date(
                    Date.now() + 86400000 * Math.ceil(Math.random() * 20)
                ),
                closeAt1: new Date(
                    Date.now() + 86400000 * Math.ceil(Math.random() * 20)
                ),
                closeAt2: new Date(
                    Date.now() + 86400000 * Math.ceil(Math.random() * 20)
                ),
            };
        });
    }

}



Thanks @Nagendra; would be good to not do that as somehow the standard related list components achieve the scrolling without such hard coding.

You can even add min-column-width="150" on datatable level to do that, is that an option for you?
